# Type inferred from readonly class property

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Given is the following test class:

```js
class Test {
    private readonly testString = "hello";
    private readonly testStringImplicit: string = "hello";

    public constructor() {
        this.testString = "world";
        this.testStringImplicit = "world";
    }
}
```

Currently, Typescript **2.8.2** (and even current 2.9.2) produces the following error for the first property `testString`:

`TS2322: Type "world" is not assignable to type "hello".`

**My Question**: Is this a bug?

I guess not, but i don't understand, why the **type** of the readonly property can be the value of them.

Thank you for every helpful answer

Comment: Just a side note: You meant `testStringExplicit`, not `testStringImplicit`. (Your first one is implicit, relying on type inference; your second one is *ex*plicit, providing the type annotation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but the type of your `testString` isn't `string`, it's `"hello"`, the [string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) with the sequence of characters `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`. Your `testStringImplicit` is explicitly typed `string`, so you can assign any string to it, but your `testString` is only allowed to have that one string literal value.

It has that type because it's `readonly`, and that's the string you initialized it with. If it weren't `readonly`, the inferred type would be `string`, but because it's `readonly`, `tsc` is assuming the initialization is the only place you're going to write to it, and so gives it the "best common type" for `"hello"`, which is the string literal type.

As [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) helpfully points out, this is [intended behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676). The relevant bullet point from that link:

> - The type inferred for a `const` variable or `readonly` property without a type annotation is the type of the initializer *as-is*.

whereas

> - The type inferred for a `let` variable, `var` variable, parameter, or non-`readonly` property with an initializer and no type annotation is the widened literal type of the initializer.

The word "constructor" doesn't appear in that pull request's text, so this effect that you can't assign a different value to `testString` in the constructor, even though you're allowed to by `readonly`'s rules, doesn't seem to be discussed there. It may be discussed elsewhere.

Comment: This behavior is [intended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), so I wouldn't file an issue about it.  I'd say the use case of "change a `readonly` property after you set it" is probably not one they would go out of their way to support...

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks for that link! I've incorporated it into the above. It's interesting, though, that tsc already goes out of its way to support "change a `readonly` property after you set it" in a constructor (which is why `this.testStringImplicit = "world";` in the question isn't an error; it *is* an error if it appears in a method instead). But I wouldn't want to be the person trying to argue that it should consider assignments in the constructor and assign the widened type if the initialization and assignment differ, not when you can just put `: string` on it. :-)

Comment: I never thought this is an intended behavior..
I'm amazed. Thank you both for ya help!